# Funções de parametros para evento click não funcionam

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou tentando grifar um texto com o evento **click** e depois "desgrifar" no segundo click, tirei a sugestão de um código que já tinha visto no [codepen](https://codepen.io/GBMahili/pen/pEvVZP)
, estou passando duas funções para o evento click, porém só a segunda funciona, código:

```
$('.texto').click(function() {

        alert(1);

    }, function() {
        alert(2);
    }
);
```

Só aparece o **alert(2)**, por que isso acontece?

Comment: Mas a função `click` só aceita uma função *handler* por vez. Se for passado dois parâmetros, o primeiro será `eventData` e apenas o segundo será o `handler` Veja a [documentação](https://api.jquery.com/click/). O que exatamente você pretende fazer?

Comment: Eu quero grifar o texto, iria usar a função css(), com text-decoration, dá uma olhada no exemplo que coloquei do codepen  que usa este conceito, ou eu deixei algo despercebido rs

Comment: Sim. No exemplo ele utiliza a função `hover` que recebe, de fato, duas funções, `handlerIn` e `handlerOut`. O `click` não funciona assim.

Comment: Ah, entendo, qual seria a melhor forma de se fazer isso?

Comment: Será o elemento `.texto` inteiro que será marcado ou algum texto que for selecionado?

Comment: O elemento texto mesmo.

Comment: Seria algo assim: https://jsfiddle.net/acwoss/1j9qcfs1/ ?

Comment: Isso, Obrigado!

Comment: Existe algum evento como esse toggle? porque também quero usar ajax, para mudar o status, seria algo como 0 e 1, só que de forma dinâmica.

Comment: Como assim evento tipo `toggle`?

Comment: Alternar entre os clicks, por exemplo, a aplicação seria uma "lista de coisas para fazer", no primeiro click, o texto é grifado, o com ajax eu mudo o status para 1, e no segundo click, seria "desgrifado" e o ajax mudaria o status para 0...

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62621/discussion-between-anderson-carlos-woss-and-ngthm4r3).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pelo o que você descreveu, basta utilizar a função `toggleClass` do jQuery para adicionar/remover uma classe CSS do elemento pressionado. Quando um elemento é pressionado, o jQuery irá verificar se ele possui a classe CSS; se não possuir, a adiciona; se possuir, a remove.

```js
$(() => {

  // Evento `click` dos elementos desejados:
  $("li").on("click", function (event) {

    // Adiciona/remove a classe CSS:
    $(this).toggleClass("selected");

  });

});
```

```css
.selected {
  font-weight: bold;
  background: cyan;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Abacaxi</li>
  <li>Banana</li>
  <li>Caqui</li>
  <li>Damasco</li>
</ul>
```